# calling plots from a function for showing in GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have these functions and one GUI with two axes (axes3 and axes4) and two edit text and one push button.

```
function z=add(x,y)
z=x+y;
end

function z=mul(x,y)
z=x*y;
end

function pre(z1,z2)
plot(handles.axes3,z1,'b*');
set(get(handles.axes3,'Title'),'String','Number of Iterations');
set(get(handles.axes3,'XLabel'),'String','Number of Comlpeted Tours');
set(get(handles.axes3,'YLabel'),'String','MIN of Lenght of Tours');

plot(handles.axes4,z2,'r*');
set(get(handles.axes4,'Title'),'String','Number of Iterations');
set(get(handles.axes4,'XLabel'),'String','Number of Comlpeted Tours');
set(get(handles.axes4,'YLabel'),'String','MIN of Lenght of Tours');
end

function main(x,y)
z1=add(x,y);
z2=mul(x,y);
pre(z1,z2);
end

function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
x=str2double(get(handles.edit1_x,'String'));
y=str2double(get(handles.edit2_y,'String'));
main(x,y);
```

and I have this error:

```
??? Undefined variable "handles" or class "handles.axes3".
Error in ==> main at 6
        plot(handles.axes3,z1,'b*');
```

How do I show our outputs in axes in GUI by calling from pre(z1,z2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can pre() access handles if you don't give it the handles? I think this may solve it.

```
function z=add(x,y)
z=x+y;
end

function z=mul(x,y)
z=x*y;
end

function pre(z1,z2,handles)
plot(handles.axes3,z1,'b*');
set(get(handles.axes3,'Title'),'String','Number of Iterations');
set(get(handles.axes3,'XLabel'),'String','Number of Comlpeted Tours');
set(get(handles.axes3,'YLabel'),'String','MIN of Lenght of Tours');

plot(handles.axes4,z2,'r*');
set(get(handles.axes4,'Title'),'String','Number of Iterations');
set(get(handles.axes4,'XLabel'),'String','Number of Comlpeted Tours');
set(get(handles.axes4,'YLabel'),'String','MIN of Lenght of Tours');
end

function main(x,y,hanldes)
z1=add(x,y);
z2=mul(x,y);
pre(z1,z2,handles);
end

function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
x=str2double(get(handles.edit1_x,'String'));
y=str2double(get(handles.edit2_y,'String'));
main(x,y,handles);
```